# Django runserver stuck on Performing system checks

Tags: django

I am running python manage.py runserver or migrate and in both commands it is getting stuck on Performing system checks...  Can you please help me out to understand what is the issue and how to solve it?

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro:driveu_backend gathole$ python manage.py runserver
/Users/gathole/.virtualenvs/du/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/models.py:4: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  from django.utils.importlib import import_module

/Users/gathole/.virtualenvs/du/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/utils.py:14: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The utilities in django.db.models.loading are deprecated in favor of the new application loading system.
  from django.db.models.loading import get_model

/Users/gathole/.virtualenvs/du/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/models.py:4: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
  from django.utils.importlib import import_module

/Users/gathole/.virtualenvs/du/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_auth/utils.py:14: RemovedInDjango19Warning: The utilities in django.db.models.loading are deprecated in favor of the new application loading system.
  from django.db.models.loading import get_model

Performing system checks...
```

Comment: Which Django are u using

Comment: Django version 1.8.1

Comment: Do u have an app called social_auth

Comment: Yes, I have and using for Google auth

Comment: That's where your problem is coming from reading from the line in your Traceback, it seems one of the utilities has been depreciated

Comment: I have another app u can use for the same purpose

Comment: Okay... but as I posted the answer, it was the issue with MySQL version. Thanks for time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL 5.7.x on Mac 14.4.0 have the same issue.

1.remove the mysql

2.brew install homebrew/versions/mysql56 (install an older version)

Answer (score 4):

just try

`pip install -U Django`

in your virtual environment.
I solve this by upgrade my Django version, without uninstall my MySQL 5.7 Server.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL latest version was causing the issue... Just reverted MySQL version to 5.6 and it worked :)

Comment: Please replace _lastest version_ with the actual version number. The latest version will change over the time.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a network problem. My code worked fine before but one day I add `client = BertClient()` in some files and I forgot to start the bert server (bert is an ML model). As a results, I encountered the same problem of starting my Django app.

You can check start from the app's `urls.py` file by commenting/uncommenting `imports`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the probable reason was my docker's Postgres and Redis were shut down, but after their running the server got me connection error
So after restarting server everything's fine