# Why is Python 3.5 crashing on a MySQL connection with correct credentials?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mariadb

I'm using Python 3.5.1, mysqlclient 1.3.9 (fork of MySQLdb that supports Python 3), and MariaDB 10.1 on Windows 10 (64-bit).

When I run

```
import MySQLdb
con = MySQLdb.connect(user=my_user, passwd=my_pass, db=my_db)
```

Python crashes.

In pycharm, I am also presented with the message

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I don't get any other errors. This is different to what happens when I run the same statements with incorrect credentials:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python35\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 191, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

This error does not occur on my CentOS server, which runs Python 3.4, mysqlclient 1.3.9, and MariaDB 10.1.

I've tried using older versions of MariaDB as suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35572662/django-runserver-stuck-on-performing-system-checks), to no avail.

What could be causing this crash and the mysterious lack of error reporting, and how can I fix it?

Edit: In my system logs, I found this entry:

General:

```
Faulting application name: python.exe, version: 3.5.1150.1013, time stamp: 0x56639598
Faulting module name: python35.dll, version: 3.5.1150.1013, time stamp: 0x56639583
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000e571c
Faulting process id: 0x4a4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d2272a22ae1a1a
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Python35\python35.dll
Report Id: 6dd874e6-5ea5-4919-af8b-4880a2c7ac5e
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Details:

```
- System 
  - Provider 
   [ Name]  Application Error 
  - EventID 1000 
   [ Qualifiers]  0 
   Level 2 
   Task 100 
   Keywords 0x80000000000000 
  - TimeCreated 
   [ SystemTime]  2016-10-15T21:21:48.041795500Z 
   EventRecordID 7615 
   Channel Application 
   Computer PETER-LENOVO 
   Security 

- EventData 
   python.exe 
   3.5.1150.1013 
   56639598 
   python35.dll 
   3.5.1150.1013 
   56639583 
   c0000005 
   00000000000e571c 
   4a4 
   01d2272a22ae1a1a 
   C:\Program Files\Python35\python.exe 
   C:\Program Files\Python35\python35.dll 
   6dd874e6-5ea5-4919-af8b-4880a2c7ac5e
```

Comment: can you log in directly using `mysql -u my_user -p my_db`  ?

Comment: @Ixer, yep, that works fine.

Comment: What about wiht `-h localhost`?

Comment: @JonStirling, that works as well.

Comment: In that case you need to double and triple check that the credentials you just tried are definitely the ones being used in your connection.

Comment: Just checking, but you tried those commands on the computer that's _not_ working, right? :P

Comment: @JonStirling, I have. When I use the wrong credentials I get the traceback mentioned above instead of the crash. (Also, yeah, I did run those on the computer that's not working.)

Comment: Do you have any errors in the MySQL or System logs when you run this program ? It might be worth tailing those.

Comment: @nemanjap I don't get any errors in the MySQL logs, but I did find an error log from the Python crash using Event Viewer. I'll edit it into my question.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is incompatible builds of your Windows/Python/MySQL library as this looks like a system thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `pycharm` but I think your problem is as @nemanjap suggests, with your `MySQLdb` installation. I just went through a similar nightmare (with Python 3.5), so I hope I can help. Here are my suggestions:

- If you haven't already, install `pip`
- Install Visual Studio Community 2015 from https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads (you only need the Python compilation tools)
- Install wheel: `pip install wheel`
- Download the MySQLdb windows binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python, specifically `mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl` (I'm 64-bit too, but I was being cautious)
- Delete the MySQLdb folder from site-packages if it exists, just in case.
- Assuming you're in the same folder as the binary download, run `pip install mysqlclient-1.3.8-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`

With a bit of luck, you should be able to connect.

---

**Notes**

On my machine, I was getting instantly aborted connections (`Got an error reading communication packets` in my `error.log`), even though my credentials were 100% correct. On the windows side, similar to OP, Python just "crashed", meaning I got a shell restart and never reaching past the `MySQLdb.connect` line. Even a `try` block didn't allow further execution (so actually a crash, as opposed to an exception or error). Thinking a compatibility issue (UNIX working totally fine), I tried to debug the `MySQLdb` in Windows, all the way to `import _mysql`, which is when I realized it was a C (compilation) issue.

Having thought all was installed well, when I executed `pip install MySQLdb-python`, I got the following:

```
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Which meant I needed to install the compilation tools for my version of Python (3.5), which is included in the VSC2015 installation. I re-ran, and then got the following:

```
Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h'
```

Which meant I needed some required headers, from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/6.0.html#downloads (again, 32-bit, just to play it safe for now). Then I got a bunch of `unresolved external symbol` errors, and realized how much I hate Windows, and installed the pre-compiled version instead. Worked wonders.

Oh, and before someone suggests a different module or method to connect, like `mysql-connector`, apart from not solving the problem, there is usually the constraint that the same code (thus, the same imported modules) should work on both Windows and UNIX machines. Plus this: http://charlesnagy.info/it/python/python-mysqldb-vs-mysql-connector-query-performance

Sorry for the long post. I needed to vent! Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I'll try out your steps later and get back to you.

Comment: Worked like a charm, accepted your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks. I had wasted a lot of time with this problem. Your solution did the trick.